# getting information from database

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

i'm watching a tutorials about CMS with OOP - PHP & RainTPL

on control page : (articles.php)

```
<?php
require_once('globals.php');
require_once(CONTROLLERS.'ArticlesController.php');

$articlesmodel = new ArticlesModel() ; 

$catsmodel     = new ArticlesCatsModel();

$controller    = new ArticlesController($articlesmodel,$catsmodel);

$controller->show();

?>
```

globals.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

define('ROOT',dirname(__FILE__));
define('INC',ROOT.'/includes/');
define('CORE',INC.'/core/');
define('MODELS',INC.'/models/');
define('CONTROLLERS',INC.'/controllers/');
define('LIBS',INC.'/libs/');

/*
core files
*/
require_once(CORE.'config.php');
require_once(CORE.'mysql.class.php');
require_once(CORE.'raintpl.class.php');
require_once(CORE.'system.php');

System::Store('db',new mysql());
System::Store('tpl',new RainTPL()); //class RainTPL
?>
```

ArticlesController.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


require_once(MODELS.'ArticlesModel.php');
require_once(MODELS.'ArticlesCatsModel.php');


class ArticlesController
{

    private $articlesModel; //Articles Model Object
    private $articlesCatsModel; //Articles Cat Model Object
                               //object of ArticlesModel class
    public function __construct(ArticlesModel $articlesmodel,ArticlesCatsModel $catsmodel)
    {

        $this->articlesModel     = $articlesmodel ;
        $this->articlesCatsModel = $catsmodel ; 
    }


    public function Show()
    {
        // array of articles from model :D 
        /*
           he takes object from Articlesmodel.php
           like private articles model 
           then he  call the Get function 
           from  ArticlesModel Class 
        */

        $articles = $this->articlesModel->Get();
        $cats     = $this->articlesCatsModel->Get();


        //put them inside the template after getting them
        System::Get('tpl')->assign('articles',$articles)    ;   
        System::Get('tpl')->assign('cats',$cats)    ;   

        // show them in the templatee

        System::Get('tpl')->draw('blog');
    }

}
```

[Blog Where articles should be shown](http://pastebin.com/h9h88wcy)

but there's no problem in Blog

the problem is that `$articles = $this->articlesModel->Get();` returns blank array doesn't contain the information from DB

The ArticlesCatsModel

[ArticlesCatsModel includes/model](http://pastebin.com/uKEPcjb4)

The ArticleModel

[ِArticlesModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fSOp.png)

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fSOp.png): http://pastebin.com/z2dzcBVc it returns blank array even there are rows in DB

---

This is Template i should see the articles that i get from DB

but the result is No Articles

to check where exactly the problem

i typed

in Articles.Controller.php

```
    $articles = $this->articlesModel->Get();
    var_dump($articles).'<br/>'; 
    $cats     = $this->articlesCatsModel->Get();
    print_r($cats);
```

and if you noticed in the picture it success when i call `$cats` but i return blank array of `$articles`

[image: Template]

Comment: Could we see the code for `articlesModel->Get()` method?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/z2dzcBVc from line 7 to 17

Comment: yes i did this mistake while i was trying i replaced it but same problem blank array

Comment: ok i will clarify more with pic

Comment: the code is too long i download it like the tutorial (RainTPL) http://pastebin.com/h9h88wcy from 183 to 195

Comment: yes and if you need screenshot of phpmyadmin i can post :)

Comment: i removed it but same problem :( http://i.imgur.com/LIu9qy9.png

Comment: i have tutorial files  of project it can help ?? you want to take look on it ?

Comment: yes ...............................

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86548/discussion-between-jo-smo-and-smile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace

```
SELETE * FROM
```

with

```
SELECT * FROM
```

in your Get() method in ArticlesModel.php file.

Comment: a small question :D :D you think     public function __construct(ArticlesModel $articlesmodel,ArticlesCatsModel $catsmodel)
    {
        $this->articlesModel = $articlesmodel; //$this->articlesModel refere to private etc the object
        $this->articlesCatsModel = $catsmodel;
    }
 better than making object like new ArticlesModel() in ArticlesController..construct is better !?

Comment: It depends, if all the parameters in your constructor are needed in order for the object to work, then the constructor with parameters is helpful, but if you should need to create an `ArticlesModel()` in a case were not all parameters would be needed, then you would have to create another constructor for it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading

Comment: i was going to get crazy :D i edited everything again because of an error with no reason i think then i get the same error as the dead page :D i copy code from original project to check i get same error then i restarted 3 times hahaah but i paste code from tmp folder if you remember then it worked i think i was the same code !! the page is crazy ! :D :D :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075143/view-page-error-php?noredirect=1#comment52047277_32075143 look :D :D :D

Comment: sorry but if you have time look at this code it makes me crazy http://pastebin.com/0SQ8jZGA        if(isset($_GET['id']) && (int)$_GET['id']>0)
will be executed & else too how in same time !!!!!

Comment: You call it recursively here: `if($this->usersModel->Update($id,$data))`, that's why both can get executed.

Comment: if($this->usersModel->Update($id,$data)) already inside else ! & if(isset($_GET['id']) && (int)$_GET['id']>0) will be executed first so else shouldn't be executed

Comment: If i would have to guess... It looks like else gets executed first and then the Update() method is called again recursively from inside the else block in the Update() method.

Comment: ok but because the id already exist so if(isset($_GET['id']) && (int)$_GET['id']>0)  will be executed so else shouldn't work

Comment: if($this->usersModel->Update($id,$data)) another function from UsersModel object :D  i feel like crazy :D

Comment: i think i know it now :D 1- updateuser.php?id=5 if will be executed then updateuser.php  will be shown  so it will call the function again and if will not work because there's no id in the url ! then it will update and draw the page (success)

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you have figured it out. :)

Comment: i think yes i understand it  :D ,,,

Comment: i finished the tutorials and the task :)) and trying to make small project that takes name and message then show them on the same page,, but i need to know while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querycheck)) why we always do that way to fetch the array ?? i don't undertstand it ?

Comment: it will be while($row = first row ) then ($row = second row ) etc .. ? this is the way to fetch the to fetch all in assoc array

Comment: Without the while, you will get only 1 row from your db.

Comment: but strange it's something like while ($row = 1) i mean we didn't type while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querycheck)) {$row = $row + 1 ;} how it already takes every row :D

Comment: maybe :D :D :D it's special for while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querycheck))

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` is a `PHP` method that gets an array of all the rows which match the query. Then you loop through the array with `while()` or just select the first one without `while()`. I hope that will help. If not, try to read the PHP documentation, it's more in detail there.

Comment: Thanks ...it was holiday :D :D D: ..i hope you are fine ^_^

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32486139/php-login-and-logout-for-website :D if you have time cheack please :D