# view page - error PHP

Tags: php, html, oop

i'm watching a tutorial i'm watching a tutorials about CMS with OOP - PHP

but while opening the users.php ( view page) i don't get any result !

on control page

users.php

```
<?php


/**
 * Globals file
 */
require_once('../globals.php');

/**
 * Articles Controller
 */
require_once(CONTROLLERS.'UsersController.php');

/**
 * Models
 */
require_once(MODELS.'UsersModel.php');



$usersmod = new UsersModel();

/**
 * Controller Instance
 */
$controller = new UsersController($usersmod);

$controller->GetAllUsers();

?>
```

users.html

```
{include="header"}

<!--main content start-->
<section id="main-content">
    <section class="wrapper">
        <!-- page start-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <section class="panel">
                    <header class="panel-heading">
                        Users
                    </header>

                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>id</th>
                            <th>name</th>
                            <th>Username</th>
                            <th>email</th>
                            <th>is admin?</th>
                            <th>Control</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {loop="users"}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{$value.id}</td>
                            <td>{$value.name}</td>
                            <td>{$value.username} </td>
                            <td>{$value.email}</td>
                            <td>{$value.is_admin}</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="updateuser.php?id={$value.id}" class="btn btn-primary">Update</a>
                                <a href="deleteuser.php?id={$value.id}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        {/loop}

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</section>


{include="footer"}
```

UsersController.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);   

class UsersController
{

    private $usersModel ; // object from model

    public function __construct(UsersModel $usersmod)
    {

        $this->usersModel = $usersmod ;


    }


    /**********************Admin Area**********************/


    public function GetAllUsers()
    {

        $users = $this->usersModel->Get();

        System::Get('tpl')->assign('users',$users);
        System::Get('tpl')->assign('users');
    }

}


?>
```

UsersModel.php

```
class UsersModel
{

    private $userInfo = array();

    /**
     * Add New user
     * @param $data
     * @return bool
     */
        public function Add($data)
        {
            if(System::Get('db')->Insert('users',$data))
                return TRUE;

            return FALSE;
        }


    /**
     * Get All Users
     */
        public function Get($extra = '')
        {
            $users = array();

            System::Get('db')->Execute("SELECT * FROM `users` {$extra}");
            if(System::Get('db')->AffectedRows()>0)
                $users = System::Get('db')->GetRows();

            return $users;
        }
```

i just get white page (blank)

no result

Comment: Blank page typically means error in your logs.

Comment: We know barely anything about your controller, templating etc., so the code you provided is close to useless.

The fact that nothing at all is printed means the template isn't even rendered.  
Check whether you have error output enabled and/or your logs.

Comment: what do you mean with logs ?? i checked the code many times

Comment: Ok i will put it @WhoIsJohnDoe

Comment: Try `$something = $controller->GetAllUsers();` otherwise the results of the query just get lost in the ether

Comment: What CMS are we talking about here?

Comment: simple cms ! what do you mean with What CMS ?

Comment: `UserController->GetAllUsers()` needs to return something like `return  System::Get('tpl')->render()`.

And that has to be printed in users.php: `echo $controller->GetAllUsers();`.

You should look at some decent already developed frameworks before building one yourself, although most of them are pretty complex.

Comment: UserController->GetAllUsers() already return because it'll call Get function

Comment: print_r($controller->GetAllUsers());
 same blank page :(

Comment: Why are both of these called? `System::Get('tpl')->assign('users',$users);` and `System::Get('tpl')->assign('users');`? Why is it neccessary to call both? Try to remove the second one.

Comment: it should be draw you're right ...put it as answer ^_^ if you don't mind ..it should be draw('users')  :)